# npx hardhat doesnt creates a new project

Tags: visual-studio-code, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I tried creating a new hardhat project. I tried the following commands in terminal.

```
npm init --yes
npm install --save-dev hardhat
```

But when I use the following command

```
npx hardhat
```

I am getting the following
[image]

I think hardhat have changed the contents. Couldnt find anything in the official document.

Can someone suggest how to create a new project using hardhat.

Edit: Contents of the folder

[image]

Comment: can you share the contents of the folder?>

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added the folder content screenshot.

Comment: I tried the same steps with the same hardhat version but failed to reproduce the errror

Comment: Are you sure there is no `hardhat.config.js` file in the directory?

Comment: Yes, hardhat.config.js file is not there, can you tell me what is ur node and npx version

Answer (score 4):

run

```
$ npx hardhat --verbose
```

You will get the location of a hardhat config file like this:

```
$ hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /home/lyon/hardhat.config.js +0ms
```

Delete it and run npx hardhat again

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it worked when I tried "yarn hardhat"

Answer (score 1):

That happens when you are trying to create a hardhat project inside a hardhat project. The same happened to me and I realized that in the parent directory I already had `hardhat.config.js` file. I had to remove that config file.